# В зависимости от нажатой Radio кнопки изменять Selct без JS

Tags: php, html

Есть несколько Radio-кнопок и один Select с Option.

Как изменять количество и значение вариантов выбора в зависимости от выбранной кнопки Radio?

Возможно ли без использования Java Script?

Например:
Нажата Radio1-в Select выпадает: -Рыба -Кошка -Хлеб
Нажата Radio2-в Select выпадает: -Кочерга -Папирус -Коробка -Малина

Comment: только с полной перезагрузкой страницы

Comment: и то, полную перезагрузку страницы нужно будет через JS делать

Answer (score 2):

Совсем без использования JS не получится. Можно сделать подачу формы на клик по radio1 или 2, заново создавать форму в PHP заполняя селект как надо.

А правильный путь - это JS + ajax + заполнять селект после ajax запроса.

Comment: Получается сделать Select в зависимости от другого Select.  В зависимости от Radio не получается.Пожалуйста подтолкните ещё.

Comment: Принцип тот же самый, на клик по радио берем его значение  и заполняем селект как надо.